# Accessing tensor value while implementing custom loss in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am implementing a custom loss function in `keras` using tensorflow as backend. The loss function gets a tensor for `y_true` and `y_pred`. My output is a `10-dimensional vector`.I need to return loss as the difference of `y_true` and `y_pred` but first I need to find the indices of `y_true` and `y_pred` to find the difference.
Lets say `y_true=[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]` and `y_pred=[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. So after decoding the value will be `y_true=4` and `y_pred=2`. So the loss is 2.
How can I decode the tensor and calculate the loss?

Comment: You want the loss to be the difference between the *indices*?

Comment: yes... difference between the indices